# Java, JavaCC: How to parse characters outside the BMP?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, javacc

I am referring to **[the XML 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-common-syn)**.

Look at the definition of `NameStartChar`:

`NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]`

If I interpret this correctly, the last range (`#x10000-#xEFFFF`) goes beyond the **UTF16 range** of Java's `char` type. So it must be **UTF32**, right? So, I need to check pairs of `char` against this range, instead of single `char`s, right?

My questions are:

- How do I check for such character ranges using standard Java methods?
- How is it possible to define such ranges in JavaCC?

  - *JavaCC complains about `\u10000` and `\uEFFFF`*

Thank you!

**NOTE:** *Don't worry, I am **not** trying to write an own XML-parser.*
**EDIT:** *I am writing a parser, which would check if text input from miscellaneous (non-XML) text formats would match valid XML names.*

Comment: Java's utterly broken *char* was conceived (to defend Gosling's SNAFU) when Unicode was not yet at 3.1.  Hence the 16-bit char SNAFU.  It got messy once Unicode 3.1 came out, because the entire char[] "abstraction" isn't really abstracting much anymore.  As Jon Skeet pointed out, the trick is to work with 32-bit codepoints (Java *int*s) and to figure out the *char-to-codepoint* relation in the String class and others.  The situation is *not* nice.  It is one of the messier aspect of Java (because it affecting a broken primitive type, deeply engrained in the language).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with UTF-32.  Notations like `#x10FFFF` and `\u10FFFF` represent characters in the abstract;  UTF-16 and UTF-32 are encodings that tell the computer how store the characters in memory.  Java always uses UTF-16, so characters outside the BMP are stored using two `char` values, or a surrogate pair. Jon has already pointed out how deal with those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `Character.toCodePoint(char, char)` which will convert a surrogate pair into a full range code point. `String.codePointAt` may well be useful to you, too.

There's a lot of other surrogate support within Character and String. To know *exactly* which methods to call, we'd need to know the exact details of your situation.

Comment: Thank you. OK, I clarified my intentions at bottom of my question (see **EDIT**).

Answer (score 0):

I've found http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10000/index.htm to be a handy site for learning about Unicode characters.

For example, u+10000 and u+10FFFF are

```
String first = "\uD800\uDC00"; // u10000
String last = "\uDBFF\uDFFF"; // u10FFFF
```